# SharePoint Parent/Child List form

Tags: list, jquery, list-view, content-editor-web-part

I'm using SharePoint 2010 standard edition and I want to create a Parent/Child list form. I noticed that Query string webpart is part of enterprise edition as shown here http://bit.ly/1tF8rkG and hence I need to find some alternate solution for this to work.

I have a product and "Product sold" list form. I have created a custom edit form and insert the child form. I want to grab the item ID from query string for parent and pass to the child form ProductName:ID (Lookup column to parent). In this example i want to show only iPhone in child form.

How this can be achieved?

Are there any OOTB approach to achieve this or I need to use JQuery?

[image]

Comment: Here is a novel approach to parent-child form data: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140095/how-can-lists-be-made-to-support-master-detail-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserted a XsltListView Webpart as child list and used the filter option to filter by ID passing the query string to Child form (as shown in this video) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiI-EJYTEp8

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question right, that you only want to see the sold iPhones when you click on iPhone in the Products List, then I would recommend you to use **WebPart Connections**.

[This blog post](http://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/05/21/connecting-web-parts-with-a-selector-and-a-detail-pane-sharepoint-2010-version/) shows (with screenshots) in Part 5 how to connect the WebParts.

## **Use Connected WebPart Feature in EditForm.aspx**

### Prepare List for changing EditForm.aspx

Go into the List settings --> Advanced Settings and on the bottom you should have a point called something like **Show Forms in a dialog** and set it to **No**.

### Go into Edit Mode of the EditForm.aspx

Go into your products list and mark a list item and click on edit. When the EditForm.aspx opens for changing the list item go to Site Actions --> Edit Page. You are now in Edit Mode of EditForm.aspx and as you can see there is already the "Products"-List WebPart on it.

### Add the "Products sold"-List WebPart to the EditForm.aspx

Just click on add a WebPart and choose the "Products sold" List.

### Connect the WebParts

Connect the WebParts as described in Part 5 in the link above. In your case the **the provider field name and your consumer field name has to be set to "Product name"**.

### Leave the Edit Mode and change the List settings back to "default"

After adding the "Products sold" List WebPart and connecting the WebParts click the "Stop Editing"-Button in the Ribbon. Go again to the List Settings --> Advanced Settings and change the **Show Forms in Dialog** to **Yes** back again.

Comment: Thanks. This is for a webpart page but i want to use EditForm.aspx

Comment: I edited my answer and added more detailed steps, because it works also in the EditForm.aspx but you have to do a little workaround in the list settings. The link I posted was only to show how the connecting of WebParts looks like. Hope that this works now for you.